# changing the position of the detailtextlabel in the cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an Iphone application in which i am combining two arrays and displaying in the same table.the problem here is i was not able to change the position of the detailed textlabel in the cell.here is my code snippet `

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_with_arrow.png"]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:img];
        [img release];        
    }
    if(newssarray==nil||[newssarray count]==0)
    {            
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *dicttable=[newssarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        head=[dicttable objectForKey:@"news"];
        head1=[dicttable objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *sub=[dicttable objectForKey:@"created"];

        NSLog (@"%@",head);

        [[cell viewWithTag:12] removeFromSuperview];
        [[cell viewWithTag:13] removeFromSuperview];
         [[cell viewWithTag:14] removeFromSuperview];

        UIButton *shopLabel=[self buttonWithText:head andFrame:CGRectMake(49, 12, 250,5)] ;
        shopLabel.tag=12;
        //shopLabel.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        [shopLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(openRestaurantsList) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UIButton *shopLabel1=[self buttonWithText:head1 andFrame:CGRectMake(49, 12, 250,5)] ;
        shopLabel1.tag=14;
        //shopLabel.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        [shopLabel1 addTarget:self action:@selector(openRestaurantsList) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(49, 30, 150,5);
        if(indexPath.row < [newsseperatearray count])
        {
            UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"news.png"];
            cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
            //NSStringEncoding encoding=NSASCIIStringEncoding;
            cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,48,48);
            cell.imageView.bounds=CGRectMake(0,0,48,48);
            [cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:NO];
            NSLog(@"%@",sub);                     
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = sub;
            cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }
        else
        {
            UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_icon.png"];
            cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
            //NSStringEncoding encoding=NSASCIIStringEncoding;
            cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,48,48);
            cell.imageView.bounds=CGRectMake(0,0,48,48);
            [cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:NO];
        }
        [cell addSubview:shopLabel];
        [cell addSubview:shopLabel1];
        // [cell addSubview:shopLabel2];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

`can anybody help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a UITableViewCell subclass, keep that cell style as `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`, and override `layoutSubviews` in that subclass. You can then change the frame of `detailTextLabel` (just make sure to call the super implementation of `layoutSubviews` in your method).